# merge cells for some records in Angular table

Tags: html, sql, angular, typescript

I am new to angular the following is the scenario:

I have a table with 10 columns.

Suppose I have different status like children,teen,young,adult,senior in column 4.

While displaying all records in Angular table, the records with senior status I need to display only 1,2,3& 4 columns with data and from 5-10 columns would be blank(actually there is data for these columns that is getting populated form data source but I need to show that as blank) and merged.

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="ds" matSort matSortDisableClear>

<!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition. -->

<!-- Request ID Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="id">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header arrowPosition="before"> 
Req Id
</mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.id}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<!-- Name Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="firstName">   
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header arrowPosition="before">    
Name 
</mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.firstName}}<br />{{row.lastName}}  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<!-- address Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="address">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header arrowPosition="before"> 
address
</mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> 

{{row.address}}
</mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<!-- Status Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="status">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header arrowPosition="before"> 
Status    
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
{{row.status}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>      

....
<!-- Other 6 columns that needs to be merged similar to Id name and address -->
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: "I have a table with 10 columns." - could you add some sample code..

Comment: @rudolf_franek updated the question with sample code

Comment: <ng-container *ngIf="status !=='Removed'">
    <!place cell data>
    </ng-container>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using a ng-container like this for each column where we need to verify Removed status and display data based on that